# Pass a value from frontend to backend without using url

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

I have a mean-stack application. In the backend, I have `api.js`:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

var body = 'response.send("hello fixed")';
var F = new Function ("request", "response", body);    
router.get('/api/special', F);

module.exports = router;
```

As a result, `https://localhost:3000/api/special` returns `hello fixed` in a browser.

Now, I want to let the front-end define the content of `body`. For example, I can make a textarea in the webpage, and users feel free to enter eg, `response.send("hello flexible")` over there. Then, I need to pass this content to nodejs, such that `https://localhost:3000/api/special` returns `hello flexible` now.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Edit 1:** Following Andrew Li's comment, I modified `api.js`:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

router.put('/endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("api.js router.put /endpoint");
    router.get('/api/special', eval('(' + req.body.value + ')'))
})

module.exports = router;
```

And in the controller:

```
app.controller('EndpointCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.body = 'function (request, response) { response.send("Hello") }';    
    $scope.changeBody = function (body) {
        return $http.put('/endpoint', { value: body })
    }
}])
```

Oddly, it works when I `put /endpoint` only for the first time, whereas later `put` does not seem to update `/api/special`. Does anyone know why?

Additionally, it takes several seconds to see the second or third `put /endpoint` in the console of the backend, which is wired.

Comment: Why do you want people on the frontend to modify your backend like that? Gigantic incoming security hole.

Comment: Sometimes, it is useful to make flexible api like [here](https://runkit.com/docs/endpoint).

Comment: But RunKit does some filtering and sanitization. You'd have to implement that too to prevent people from using your app as a vector of attack.

Comment: Well, i will... but in the first place, I need to know how they made it possible...

Comment: You could set up an endpoint to receive function bodies like `/api/create_endpoint/`, then POST to that URL to create a new endpoint with input value.

Comment: I see... Additionally, I want users to be able to enter `function (request, response) { response.send("Hello") }` and the backend to accept that. Do you know how to change the code to achieve this?

Comment: Other than `eval`ing, I would say use static analysis with something like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) to get the arguments and the body of the function.

Comment: Again, at this stage, I am not against `eval`. I tried `router.get('/api/special', eval(newbody))`, but it gave me an error.

Comment: Try `eval('(function(request, response) { … })')` -- the function must be wrapped in parentheses or else it will be interpreted as a function statement. Make sure to sanitize your inputs before evalling!

Comment: Indeed, `eval('(function(request, response) { … })')` works...

Comment: Please see **Edit 1** in my OP.

Comment: `put /endpoint` is *appending* to the `get /api/special/` route, but the secondary registrations will only be invoked if `next()` is called in the previous invocations. Instead you should register the route once outside of `put /endpoint`, passing in an intermediary that will invoke your new function. I.e., `router.get( '/api/special', ( ...args ) => f( ...args ) )`, then manipulate variable `f` in `put /endpoint`.

Comment: @vox Sorry, `router.get( '/api/special', ( ...args ) => f( ...args ) )` is written per se or should I complete the `...` with something else? Additionally, should I add  `next()` or not? Don't you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here is a soluton in the same vein as your example, but instead uses a middleware that invokes a variable.

```
const express = require( "express" );
const app = express();

function rawBody( req, res, next ) {

    req.setEncoding( "utf8" );
    req.body = "";
    req.on( "data", chunk => req.body += chunk );
    req.on( "end", next );

}

app.use( rawBody );

const router = express.Router();

// f is our variable; we initialize it to just call next, likely resulting in a 404
let f = ( req, res, next ) => next();

// use an intermediary function to invoke f
// don't use just f, which is passed by value and wouldn't update
router.get( "/api/special", ( ...args ) => f( ...args ) );

router.put( "/endpoint", ( req, res ) => {

    // update f
    f = eval( "(" + req.body + ")" );

    // send a response; otherwise the request will hang
    res.sendStatus( 200 );

} );

app.use( router );

app.listen( 3000 );
```

The [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) works in two ways: collections function parameters into an array or expands an array as parameters. This is valid syntax for Node LTS or later. You could also explicitly use `( req, res )`.

I must stress such an endpoint is extremely vulnerable, as it can use require, from which it can do anything the process has permission to do (such as downloading and installing software). [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2) is an npm module that could potentially help, but they offer no actual guarantee of safety. I suggest you execute code in a sandbox and only grant that sandbox limited permission (such as no access to the filesystem or network).

Comment: Thank you very much... Now, I open `https://localhost:3000/endpoint` and enter `function (request, response) { response.send("Hallo") }`, and open `https://localhost:3000/api/special` in another tab, I expect to see `Hallo`, but I cannot see it. I add `console.log(f.toString())` inside `router.get( "/api/special"...`, it shows that `f` was not updated.

Comment: My example uses `req.body` while yours used `req.body.value`. Can you verify that whichever you're using is the string you're passing in?

Comment: Now I use `req.body` as well, and it is indeed whatever I am passing in.

Comment: The only other issue I can imagine is that the `f` updated in `put /endpoint` is not the same `f` used in `get /api/special`. Are both routes (and `f`) declared in the same file? I've updated my example to include my entire example file that I tested to work in Chrome, FF, IE11, and Edge.

Comment: Yes, both routes and `f` are in the same file... I just realized that it is `f = eval( "(" + req.body + ")" );` does not work, because all the commands after that do not be executed. It seems that it needs some special header...

Comment: My bad, I should use `f = eval( "(" + req.body.value + ")" )` because I have a different structure of `req.body`. It works now... thank you!